# How find this sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{L_{n}(2)}{n^4}=?$

Tags: summation

**Question:**

> Find the sum
>   $$I=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{L_{n}(2)}{n^4}=?$$
>   where
>   $$L_{n}(k)=1-\dfrac{1}{2^k}+\dfrac{1}{3^k}-\cdots+\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^k}$$

since
$$L_{n}(2)=1-\dfrac{1}{2^2}+\dfrac{1}{3^2}-\cdots+\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^2}$$
so
$$I=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1-\dfrac{1}{2^2}+\dfrac{1}{3^2}-\cdots+\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^2}}{n^4}$$

Then I can't Continue

Comment: It's rather close to $1+\dfrac{\sqrt C}{10\cdot\ln(2+\sqrt3)}$ , where *C* is [Catalan's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan's_constant), but I doubt that's the actual value.

Comment: It seems *a bit* difficult... Can you specify which tools are supposed to be used? That is, what is the context of the problem? (Integration, number theory, Riemann's zeta function...)

Comment: @ajotatxe,this problem is from china peopele,He very like research
such this sum.and Now he can't find this.and He think it can find it the value

Comment: Mathematica tells us that

$$I=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{12n^4}\left(\pi^2-3(-1)^n\zeta\left(2,\frac{1+k}{2}\right)+3(-1)^n\zeta\left(2,\frac{2+k}{2}\right)\right).$$

Here $\zeta(s,a)$ is the [Hurwitz zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function). Maybe this helps a bit?

Comment: Some integral reps for $I$: $${\frac {1}{1080}}\,{\pi }^{6}+\int _{0}^{1}\!{\frac {\ln  \left( u
 \right) \mathrm{polylog} \left( 4,-u \right) }{1+u}}{du}={\frac {59}{30240}}\,{\pi }^{6}+\int _{0}^{\infty }\!{\frac {t\mathrm{polylog} \left( 4,-{{\rm e}^{-t}} \right) }{1+{{\rm e}^{-t}}}}{dt}\approx1.063582242
$$

Comment: You can rearrange it a bit as $$I=\sigma_a(2,4)+\frac{31}{32}\zeta(6)=\sigma_a(2,4)+\frac{31}{30240}\pi^6,$$ where $\sigma_a(2,4)$ is as in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerSum.html. However, I haven't found any simple expression for $\sigma_a(2,4)$ in terms of standard constants, and suspect none is known.